# Prove $\int ^{1/2}_0\frac{\cos \pi x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\leq \frac{1}{4}\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Comment: From the solution below, it seems that there missing a square root on the right side... But this is how the problem in the textbook gave me, probably the problem made a typo here.

Prove $$\int ^{1/2}_0\frac{\cos \pi  x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\leq \frac{1}{4}\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2}$$
I tried 
$$\int ^{1/2}_0\frac{\cos \pi  x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\leq\int ^{1/2}_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
Let $$x=\tan \theta$$
So
$$\int ^{1/2}_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\int^{\tan^{-1}(1/2)}_0\frac{\sec^2 \theta}{\sec \theta}d\theta=\int^{\tan^{-1}(1/2)}_0\sec\theta d\theta=\ln|\sec \theta+\tan \theta|^{\tan^{-1}(1/2)}_0=\ln(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2})$$
But I do not know how to approach the the sulution I need to prove, any help? Thank you~

Comment: the inequality is wrong:

$$
I\approx 0.3113
$$

whereas $$\arctan(1/2)/4 \approx 0.1159 $$

Comment: What about proving the sharper $$\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\cos(\pi x)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,dx \leq -\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}+3\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$$ ? ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that there is a square missing in the left hand side, since the inequality as stated is false. Then by [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality):

$$\left(\int_0^{\tfrac12}\frac{\cos(\pi x)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\mathrm{d}x\right)^2 \leq \int_0^{\tfrac12} \cos^2(\pi x)\mathrm{d}x \cdot \int_0^{\tfrac12} \frac1{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x = \tfrac14 \arctan(\tfrac12)$$